# Unity, private value not updated in script prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create some spell than can be used by both the Player & the Enemies.
So, I've created a script "BasicAttack" as you can see below.

```
public class BasicAttak : Spell {
    public int          dmg = 2;
    public float        speed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody    projectile; 
    private float       currentCooldown = 0.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        currentCooldown = 0.0f;
    }

    public override bool    launch(Vector3 launcherPosition, Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Debug.Log("Launch Basic Attack, cooldown = " + this.currentCooldown + " - if = " + (this.currentCooldown <= 0.0f) );
        if (this.currentCooldown <= 0.0f) {
            if (projectile == null)
                return (false);
            Quaternion r = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPosition - launcherPosition);
            Rigidbody shot = Instantiate (projectile, launcherPosition, r) as Rigidbody;
            ProjectileScript a = shot.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
            a.damage = this.dmg;
            a.speed = this.speed;
            this.currentCooldown = this.cooldown;
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    void    Update()
    {
        if (this.currentCooldown > 0.0f)
            this.currentCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("currentCooldown = "+currentCooldown);
    }
}
```

Because I want to use this script to create different type of spell (using the damage and speed parameter), I've create some GameObject, one for each spell.

I've assigned my script to each Gameobject and set different values to each variables.
Then, once everything configured, I've created prefabs for those spells like this one:
[image: Unity Spell Prefab]

Everything seems fine so far. So, I've assigned my prefab to the player spell slot, I've launched the game and I've tried to launch a spell.
The very first spell is working but, for the second spell, the variable `currentCooldown` is never reset.
Here is what I get in the console.

> **Launch Basic Attack, cooldown = 0.5 - if = False**
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) BasicAttak:launch(Vector3, Vector3) (at
> Assets\MyAsset\Scripts\Spell\BasicAttak.cs:18)
> ACharacter:LaunchSpell(Int32) (at
> Assets\MyAsset\Scripts\ACharacter.cs:70) Player:FixedUpdate() (at
> Assets\MyAsset\Scripts\Player.cs:20)   (Filename:
> Assets/MyAsset/Scripts/Spell/BasicAttak.cs Line: 18)
>
> **currentCooldown = 0**
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) BasicAttak:Update() (at
> Assets\MyAsset\Scripts\Spell\BasicAttak.cs:42)

At exactly the same frame, the currentCooldown variable is displayed at 0.5 in the launch function and at 0 in the update function. When it's the same variable in the exact same script in one prefab.

If I want to launch another spell, I can't just stop and play the game again. I have to relaunch Unity just to have my first spell launched.

It seems quite mystical to me, and I'm not even sure which question to ask. How can I do to have the same value for my variable ?

Note: If, instead of assigning a prefab to my player spell slot, I assign a GameObject from the scene, this problem doesn't occur. But, I can't really use this "solution" because I have to create one GameObject for each enemy that will also use the spell. Which mean that if I have 786 enemy, I need to create 786 GameObject and assign the spell manually to each enemy.

Comment: What happens if you move the second Debug.Log to the start of the Update() method? Before Time.deltaTime is applied to currentCooldown?

Comment: You should evaluate a TimeSpan (DateTime.UTCNow - LastFireTime > Cooldown) upon fire rather than updating every frame to check the time that's passed.

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse Unity3D's inspector has a debug mode which shows private variables. You can enable it in the dropdown menu [shown here](http://imgur.com/u7m6AWQ)

Comment: Where do you fire your launch? I mean, in witch Unity's main lifecycle loop (Update, LateUpdate, Some Event...)?

Comment: How do you instantiate the prefabs? Are you sure, that there is a prefab for each "setup"?

Comment: @Eraph The exact same happens. It seems like the variable is always at 0.

Comment: @Frohlich I instantiate my launch in a FixedUpdate. Right after an Input.keypress is trigerred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in Unity in most case `Update` method is called more frequently then the `FixedUpdate` method. As a fact `Update` is called once per frame but frequency for `FixedUpdate` method depends on your `Fixed Timestep` settings (look into `Edit > Project Settings > Time`). It may be called once after every 3 frames. Hence the problem Fixed update display something and Update displaying something else.

As a fix you should use `Invoke` instead of update. Here's how

```
public class BasicAttak : Spell {
    public int          dmg = 2;
    public float        speed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody    projectile; 
    private float       currentCooldown = 0.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        currentCooldown = 0.0f;
    }

    public override bool    launch(Vector3 launcherPosition, Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Debug.Log("Launch Basic Attack, cooldown = " + this.currentCooldown + " - if = " + (this.currentCooldown <= 0.0f) );
        if (this.currentCooldown <= 0.0f) {
            if (projectile == null)
                return (false);
            Quaternion r = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPosition - launcherPosition);
            Rigidbody shot = Instantiate (projectile, launcherPosition, r) as Rigidbody;
            ProjectileScript a = shot.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>();
            a.damage = this.dmg;
            a.speed = this.speed;
            this.currentCooldown = this.cooldown;
            Invoke("ResetCoolDown", this.cooldown);
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    void ResetCoolDown()
    {
        this.currentCooldown = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

*If you don't know about `Invoke`*

```
public void Invoke(string methodName, float time);
```

will call the method (method name provided in `string methodName` parameter) after time provide in `float time` parameter so in `Invoke("ResetCoolDown", this.cooldown);` `Invoke` will call the method `ResetCoolDown` after `this.cooldown` time (which is set to 0.5f) in your case.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution, I'll try it tomorrow (don't have access to the project right now)

Comment: This is exactly why I've asked "when you call your lunch" Gary. Anas's solution should work just fine.